# Using excel, If a string of interest is present within the cell, cut that string out, then paste in a new column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For instance the values in the column have a mix of two properties: Code and Color

I cannot use the `text to columns` because there is no punctuation mark separating them and plenty of spaces in between.

**For example:**

Code: SLV 1234 GGA2

Color: AQUA BLUE

**What the problem is:**

Current Column = SLV 1234 GGA2 AQUA BLUE

**What I need:**

Current Column = SLV 1234 GGA2

Next Column = AQUA BLUE

Comment: You'll need a list of valid colors.  Then you can check your string against the list to see which one you need to split out.

Answer (score 1):

You can also choose *Space* als delimiter (Step 4):
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-convert-text-to-columns-wizard-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7

Edit based on comment:

If color ist always the last (one single) Word in cell A1:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ", REPT(" ", 100)), 100))
```

Edit2:

If you don't have that many colors, you could do something like:

- `search` every color one by one. If it's found, you'll get the position, if not, an error will be thrown (so replace it with `999`, I'll tell shortly why).
- Next take the `min` value of all found positions, so that if you have `BLUE` and `AQUA BLUE` inside the search, `AQUA BLUE` will be returned (instead of the `BLUE` substring)
- Take the `right` part of the cell, subtracting the found position+1. If nothing is found, `999` will be subtracted, so it throws an error, replace it with `" "`.

Probably not an elegant solution, but maybe it works for you.

[image]

The english-formula would be:

```
=IFERROR(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-MIN(IFERROR(SEARCH("SEE GREEN";A1);999);IFERROR(SEARCH("AQUA BLUE";A1);999);IFERROR(SEARCH("BLUE";A1);999))+1);"")
```

Maybe there is one typo inside, cannot check it because of german excel :(

Comment: Problem is there are lots of spaces in between I forgot to point that out. Revised main post

Comment: If color is always the last (one single) word, you could use right and subsitute. I edited my answer.

Comment: Sorry. One more addition. Colors can be 2 words (e.g. Aqua Blue, Matte Gold, Sky Blue, and etc.). Is there something that can look up the string inside the column? For example I look up Aqua Blue

Comment: edit 2 added. Works if you dont have to many colors (or have a lot of time to modify the formula ;-))

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create a list of all the acceptable colors.  Sort that list by the length of the color description, descending.

Then you can use these formulas:

**Code**

```
B1: =IFERROR(LEFT(A1,AGGREGATE(15,6,SEARCH(Colors,A1),1)-1),A1)
```

**Color**

```
C1:  =IFERROR(MID(A1,AGGREGATE(15,6,SEARCH(Colors,A1),1),99),"")
```

The `IFERROR` function is there to return the **code** and **null string** if there is no matching color listed in the string.

Also, this algorithm depends on there being no strings matching a color within the code segment.

[image]